# How can I change desktop shortcut name and icon of an installer?

Tags: icons

I wonder if I can change the application name and desktop icon of a product's without installing it first?

Briefy I want to customize .msi installer package to change default application name and it's desktop icon.

Thanks

Comment: What framework are you using to author the MSI?

Comment: I am not related with software programming dude, so I don't understand you question clearly. Think about iTunes for instance. I have iTunes installer as .msi package. When we deploy this software to our corporate users I want them to see customized icon and name on their desktops instead of original iTunes icon and name.

Comment: This is a programming website, so it probably belongs at Superuser.com but if you want to change an MSI, you need to be able to alter the package, which you can't do simply. Try looking at Orca or some other utility to change MSI packages.